# return from incompatible pointer type (const vs non-const). C/GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I have following piece of code:

```
typedef uint8_t array_t[8];
static array_t _my_array;
static const array_t * foo(void) {
    return &_my_array; // <-- return from incompatible pointer type
}
```

how do I fix this error? what am I doing wrong?
do I have to cast _my_array as `(const array_t *)`? Shouldn't cast from pointer to `const` pointer be implicit?

Note:

```
return _my_array;
```

works *as* well, i.e. compiles with the same warning.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but the use of the identifier `_my_array` is ill-advised.  C99 7.1.3: "All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with ﬁle scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."

Comment: isn't `static array_t _my_array` file scoped?

Comment: Yes, it is -- and that's the problem.  Such identifiers are reserved *to the implementation*; you're not allowed to use them yourself.  Later in the same section: "If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved [...] the behavior is undefined."  The implementation (the compiler or a predefined header) is permitted to declare its own file-scope entity named "_my_array".  The latest C99 draft is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `const`; the function returns `const array_t *` (pointer to const array_t), but the returned expression, `&_my_array`, is of type `array_t *`, and the two types are not compatible.

The simplest fix is to drop the `const` from the return type:

```
typedef uint8_t array_t[8];
static array_t _my_array;
static array_t * foo(void) {
    return &_my_array;
}
```

**EDIT**:

I'm hesitant to suggest a compiler bug, but I've come up with a test program that I think indicates either a bug in gcc or a very obscure aspect of the C standard.

```
typedef int this_type;
typedef int that_type[8];

static this_type this;
static that_type that;

static const this_type *this_func(void) {
    return &this;
}

static const that_type *that_func(void) {
    return &that;
}
```

When I compile this with `gcc -c -std=c99 -pedantic-errors c.c` (gcc 4.5.2), I get:

```
c.c: In function ‘that_func’:
c.c:12:5: error: return from incompatible pointer type
```

Why does it complain about an implicit conversion from `that_type*` to `const that_type*`, but not about a conversion from `this_type*` to `const this_type*`.

Since `that_type` is a *typedef*, it's an alias for an array type, and `that_type*` is a pointer to an array (not a pointer to an element of an array); there is no array-to-pointer conversion as far as I can tell.  I don't *think* the fact that `this_type` is an integer type and `that_type` is an array type should make any difference.

Another data point: on Solaris 9, `cc -c -Xc c.c` doesn't complain.

Logically, converting a pointer to *foo* to a pointer to const *foo* should be safe; it doesn't produce any opportunity to violate const-correctness.

If I'm right, then the code in the question is valid, gcc's warning is incorrect, and you can work around it either by dropping the `const` on the function definition (make it return `array_t*` rather than `const array_t*`, or by adding a cast on the return statement:

```
return (const array_t*)&_my_array;
```

If I'm wrong, I expect someone will point it out soon.

(My use of `this`, a C++ keyword, as an identifier is somewhat deliberate.  This is a C question.  I understand that C++ has slightly different rules in this area.)

**EDIT2:**
I've just submitted a [gcc bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50662).

**EDIT3:**
Joseph S. Myers responded to my bug report:

> This is not a bug.  You can implicitly convert "pointer to int" to
>   "pointer to const int", but not "pointer to array of int" to "pointer
>   to array of const int" (see 6.5.16.1), and "const that_type *" is
>   "pointer to array of const int" (there is no such type as "pointer to
>   const array of int", which would be a permitted target of such a
>   conversion; see 6.7.3#8).

Comment: clang isn't happy either. `warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'that_type *' (aka 'int (*)[8]') from a function with result type 'that_type const *' (aka 'int const (*)[8]')`

Comment: I think clang tries to be compatible with gcc.  It's possible that they just reproduced this bug.  We'll see how the gcc maintainers respond to my bug report.

Comment: @Keith. Please post an answer quoting Joseph's response then I can accept it.

Comment: Both gcc 5, and clang 3.7 don't complain about this.

Answer (score 1):

[Answered by Joseph S. Myers](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50662)

> This is not a bug.  You can implicitly convert "pointer to int" to
>   "pointer to const int", but not "pointer to array of int" to "pointer
>   to array of const int" (see 6.5.16.1), and "const that_type *" is
>   "pointer to array of const int" (there is no such type as "pointer to
>   const array of int", which would be a permitted target of such a
>   conversion; see 6.7.3#8).